# Audio lagging when no screen updates are happening in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, audio, virtual-machine

I've got a VirtualBox VM on Arch Linux running Mac OS X 10.6, and when it plays audio, if my cursor is still and nothing on the guest display is moving/updating, the audio starts lagging. If I shake my mouse really fast (in the guest window), it plays smoothly until I stop moving my mouse.
If there is a progress bar moving on screen, the audio will play smooth until it disappears or stops moving on screen.

Changing the audio format to 22050.0 Hz in Audio MIDI Setup seems to make it stutter/lag less, but there is still a lot of stutter.

So, how do I fix this? And is it an issue in the guest (Mac) or the host (Arch Linux)?

Comment: You have no official guest additions to map to the hardware properly - because you're running an OS not licensed for virtualisation on non-Apple hardware… and in fact if you're running the client edition of Snow Leo you're running a version of OS X not licensed for virtualisation at all, on any hardware.

Comment: Does it make it any better that the host is an iMac from mid-2011 (but runs Linux not macOS) so technically it's a version of OS X running on Apple hardware, but just virtualised?

Comment: Marginally - but there are still no official guest additions for Snow Leo, because it's not licensed to VM. Some VM apps 'respect' this [i.e irritate the user] by not allowing Snow Leo to run. VB does… but it's just not very good compared to Fusion or Parallels [which of course won't run on  raw nix] I have a VM of Snow Leo Server here, running on a 2009 Mac Pro… just fine, I actually run an old version of Cubase in it, so it's handling multiple audio tracks at once with no issues, but it's in Parallels & has official support.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fixed it. So, I installed OS X 10.6 in EFI mode without any bootloader, and then turned off the VM. I disabled the EFI option, and used iBoot to boot into the hard drive.

Sure enough, booting into the hard drive with iBoot fixed it!

It also seems to have fixed microphone input too and QuickTime Player's built-in audio recording & screen recording functions no longer error when starting a recording.

I'll leave this here for future visitors & accept this as the answer when I can.